# Multiple hints or multiple style for the same hint in edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

How to add to an EditText component another hint that will react as an hint, but with different as the default hint.

For example: field name is city, so I would like the primary hint in black to be displayed as "city" and in light blue I would like it to be dislayed as "tap to select a city".

Are there any ready-to-go components or xml attributes for it?
Is this a case where I need Java code and implement onfocus and show/hide another TextView that will react as label?

---

I got this as strings.xml:

```
<string name="fld_fullname">
    <![CDATA[
        <font color="#8B8B8B">City</font> <font color="#BABABA">tap to change</font>
    ]]>
</string>
```

and this in Java code:

```
etCity.setHint(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.fld_city)));
```

Now, how can I take the color from colors.xml? Might I use placeholders or is there a better way?
Asking for best practice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one hint attribute to EditText although you can add multi-colored hint programmatically like this

```
myEditView.setHint(Html.fromHtml("city - <font color='blue'>tap to select a city</font>."));
```

EDIT: if you are taking values from string.xml and color.xml then do following:

```
myEditView.setHint(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.hint1)+" <font color='"+getResources().getColor(R.color.hintColor)+"'>"+getString(R.string.hint2)+"</font>."));
```

Comment: Do you know how to change it so the color would be taken from colors.xml and the string from strings.xml?
I'm editing my question and mark your initial solution as answer