# Is this possible to change a portion of hint's color in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `AppCompatEditText` Inside `TextInputLayout` and set a hint from string resource.

```
<string name="company_name">Companyname <font fgcolor='#FF0000'>&#42;</font></string>
```

The color of the star is not changing to red.

This is what What I got.

[image]

What I want (edited in photoshop)

[image]

I tried drawableEnd with an image, but the AppCompatEditText has the width as "match_parent". So its displayed at the end. I don't what that way. Is there any way to do it.

UPDATE :

Tried this:

```
company_name.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<small><i>" + "Text Hint Here" + "</i><font color=#FF0000>&#42;</font></small>"));
```

This is what I got. The old hint is not replaced by new one. Both hints are showing.

[image]

Comment: set Hint for `edittext` in your code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405661/is-it-possible-to-change-the-text-color-in-a-string-to-multiple-colors-in-java)

Comment: Yeah, that's not gonna work. That hint is drawn with a single, basic `Canvas#drawText()` call. It'd take some nontrivial modifications to `TextInputLayout` and its helper class to make that happen.

Comment: look into this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758981/multiple-hints-or-multiple-style-for-the-same-hint-in-edittext

Comment: Tried it. Not working as expected. Got this https://imgur.com/a/Fr8iQ

Comment: Its not replacing old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent possible ...

here are my findings

1. `Html/Spannable` on `Floating` text of `TextInputEditText` is not working.

   `txt_usemail.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#707E90\">" + "Companyname" + "</font>" + "<font color=\"#FF0000\">" + "*" + "</font>"));`

[image: 1]

2. `Html/Spannable` on `TextInputLayout` hint is not working.

   `txt_usemail.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#707E90\">" + "Companyname" + "</font>" + "<font color=\"#FF0000\">" + "*" + "</font>"));`

[image: 2]

3. `Html/Spannable` on `TextInputEditText` is working.

   `et_usemaill.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#707E90\">" + "Companyname" + "</font>" + "<font color=\"#FF0000\">" + "*" + "</font>"));`

[image: 3]

Now, problem here is if you `setHint()` on `TextInputEditText`(like point 3) then `Floating` text won't work.

[image]

to use `Floating` text, we need to `setHint()` on `TextInputLayout`

Here is the trick using `EditText` focus/defocus

```
final TextInputLayout txt_usemail = findViewById(R.id.txt_usemail);
final TextInputEditText et_usemaill = findViewById(R.id.et_usemaill);


et_usemaill.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#707E90\">" + "Companyname" + "</font>" + "<font color=\"#FF0000\">" + "*" + "</font>"));

et_usemaill.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {

            if (et_usemaill.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                if (hasFocus) {
                    et_usemaill.setHint(null);
                    txt_usemail.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#c5c5c5\">" + "Companyname" + "</font>" + "<font color=\"#FF0000\">" + "*" + "</font>"));
                } else {
                    // Remove Glitch/Smooth Animation
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            txt_usemail.setHint(null);
                            et_usemaill.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#707E90\">" + "Companyname" + "</font>" + "<font color=\"#FF0000\">" + "*" + "</font>"));
                        }
                    }, 200);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#c5c5c5</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:id="@+id/txt_usemail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_usemaill"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Result -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
change edittext hint color :-
 android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
TextInputLayout
 android:textColorHint="#707E90"
....................................................
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/txt_usemail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="#707E90">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_usemaill"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:hint="@string/res_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
.............................................................
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the library named Spanny. With the help of this, we can include and can customize each and every character with different, color, font size, font style and many more things. And it can be used to set the hint as well as setting the text.

This is the link to the library [Spanny](https://github.com/binaryfork/Spanny)

```
Spanny spanny = new Spanny("Underline text", new UnderlineSpan())
            .append("Company Name ")
            .append("*", new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED));
```

you can set that Spanny object by this:

```
textView.setHint(spanny);
```

or this:

```
textView.setText(spanny);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to change color for the hint, not for text.

Comment: @VigneshKM this will customize the string and then you can set the string to hint or text it's your choice.

Comment: Tried it! It's working like the Html.fromHtml() only. Not as we expected. But Thanks, I can use this library any other place.

Answer (score 0):

Just set hint for the 
--- `<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>`
that contains
------ `<EditText>`
in your code

Code (Kotlin):

```
your_til_id.hint = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.your_hint_str)+ "<font color='red'>*</font>")
```

Layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout 
    android:id="@+id/your_til_id"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/your_et_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to change the hint color of TextInputLayout. Like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:theme="@style/textinputlayout">

 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="Company Name"
     android:id="@+id/edit_id"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Create textinputlayout file in styles folder

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
  <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
  <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/Color Name</item> 
  <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
  <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/Color Name</item>
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/Color Name</item>
  <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/Color Name</item>
</style>
```

Set To Main Theme of App,It Works Only Highlight State Only

```
 <item name="colorAccent">@color/Color Name</item>
```

Note: This solution is not supported in api 16 or below. For that you are require to do this:

To change bottom line color, you can use this in your app theme:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
```

To change floating label color

```
<style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/main_color</item>
```

and use it like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
...
 app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
 android:textColorHint="#c1c2c4">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want part of hint color should change. Not entire hint color.